# Dynamic variables in json with Django settings values

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am working with a python library for a certain api service. And in order to connect to their account, they use the json file.
This is how the API connection looks like.

```
api = VoximplantAPI('credentials.json')
```

credentials.json

```
 {
  "account_email": "my email",
  "account_id": "ac_id",
  "key_id": "key_id",
  "private_key": "private"
}
```

I removed the values.
I have a question, how can I add dynamic variables to json so that I can take values ​​from Django settings, for example using Jinja. I have been looking for an answer for several hours, but I have not found an answer.

Comment: you can use environment variables which is a common way to do it

Answer (score 0):

Json in python is technically Dictionary, so you can update the same way you update dictionary

For example,

```
a = {"a": 123}
b = {"b": 456}
```

And by writing `a.update(b)` you will get in response

```
{"a": 123, "b": 456}
```

The same way loop through all the data you wan to add in json
For example,

```
final_json =  {
  "account_email": "my email",
  "account_id": "ac_id",
  "key_id": "key_id",
  "private_key": "private"
}
users = User.objects.filter(name="test")
temp_dict = {}

count = 1
for user in users:
    temp_dict.update({f"first_name{count}": user.first_name})
    count += 1
```

And then update your `final_json` by

```
final_json.update(temp_dict)
```

You will get your json as:

```
 {
  "account_email": "my email",
  "account_id": "ac_id",
  "key_id": "key_id",
  "private_key": "private",
  "first_name1": "value_1",
  "first_name2": "value_2",
   ..
   ..
   ..
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I don't need to update this data. At the moment they are stored as static variables in json, which is not good. I need variables in this file to be taken from another file and inserted dynamically to hide private keys)

Comment: From variables in JSON, do you mean key in key-value pair from JSON?